# Cómo detectar conexión a Internet y poner un mensaje de aviso si no hay conexión

Tags: android, webview

en algunas actividades muestr un sitio web contenidos en un WebView, en los casos en los que el dispositivo no tenga datos o no se encuentre enganchado a una conexion wifi quisiera mostrar un mensaje agradable posiblemente con alguna imagen donde se le avise al usuario que para ver el contenido necesita conexión a internet.

Por ejemlo en la siguiente vista:

```
public class Fragment_Home extends Fragment {

public Fragment_Home() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    String url="http://www.uniagustiniana.edu.co/";
    WebView view=(WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.wv_home);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());// Agregamos un WebViewCliente, esto permite que se sigan ejecutando los links dentro de este WebView
    view.loadUrl(url);

    return v;
}
}
```

Archivo xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.tecnologias.uniagustapp.fragmentos.Fragment_Home">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wv_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Actualmente cuando el equipo no tiene acceso a internet me muestra esta pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes agregar un html que desees mostrar dentro de `/assets` y cargarlo cuando no exista conectividad.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</HEAD>
<BODY LANG="en-US" BGCOLOR="#ffffff" DIR="LTR">
<H3><center>Se requiere conexión a internet.</center></H3>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

El archivo en este caso se agrega dentro de :

```
   /assets/html/pagina_error.html
```

Si requieres saber si hay internet disponible, debes revisar si existe conectividad con [**isAvailable()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isAvailable()) y si existe conectividad y es posible establecer conexión con [**isConnected()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnected())

```
private static ConnectivityManager manager;

public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Usando el método anterior podemos determinar si hay conectividad y si es posible establecer una conexión.

```
    public class Fragment_Home extends Fragment {

    public Fragment_Home() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        String url="http://www.uniagustiniana.edu.co/";
        WebView view=(WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.wv_home);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());// Agregamos un WebViewCliente, esto permite que se sigan ejecutando los links dentro de este WebView
        //view.loadUrl(url);

        /****************************************/    
        if (isOnline(getActivity())) {
            String url="http://www.uniagustiniana.edu.co/";
            view.loadUrl(url);
        } else {
            view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/pagina_error.html");
        }
        /****************************************/


        return v;
    }

}
```

---

Recuerda usar `getActivity()` como contexto si te encuentras dentro de un `Fragment`,

```
isOnline(getActivity())
```

si te encuentras en una `Activity` puedes usar el contexto de la aplicación mediante `getApplicationContext()`

```
isOnline(getApplicationContext())
```

Muy importante agregar los permisos, para determinar el estatus de la red y tener permisos de internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Gracias, agregué un Toast.makeText en los condicionales, entra por el if cuando tiene conexión pero cuando no tiene no muestra el texto

Comment: El toast necesita el contexto, como lo estas generando?

Comment: Si tiene el contexto Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"NO hay conexión!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); si puedes porfa hechale un vistazo **[Proyecto](https://github.com/ivanlobeloc/UniagustApp)** :D

Comment: @Alfredo como primer detalle usa las clases de soporte por ejemplo usa preferentemente el import:  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: Si me tocó cambiarla por android.app.Fragment; porque me generaba error en el Main Activity con unas instancias a cada Fragment para las transacciones, voy a generar una nueva pregunta para ver si es posible cambiar esta librería. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Definitivamente debes usar las librerías de soporte por ejemplo en lugar de getFragmentManager() usar getSupportFragmentManager(), voy a subir estos cambios a tu proyecto te parece bien para que funcione correctamente lo que tienes hasta ahora

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67410/discussion-on-answer-by-jorgesys-como-detectar-conexion-a-internet-y-poner-un-me).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67411/discussion-between-alfredo-and-jorgesys).

Comment: disculpa me puedes ayudar con esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/111677/34903

Answer (score 4):

Para saber si hay conexión a Internet utiliza las clases `ConnectivityManager` y `NetworkInfo`, con estas clases obtendrás la información que necesitas para saber si hay conexión a Internet o no. Después, solo tienes que utilizar un **condicional**, el cual si es verdadero carga la pagina web y si es falso carga un mensaje de error. El mensaje de error lo puedes cargar desde una url, un archivo html o un String.

Para utilizar las clases `ConnectivityManager` y `NetworkInfo` tienes que agregar los siguientes permisos al **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

#### Fragment_Home

```
public class Fragment_Home extends Fragment {

    public Fragment_Home() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        WebView view=(WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.wv_home);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());// Agregamos un WebViewCliente, esto permite que se sigan ejecutando los links dentro de este WebView

        // Comprueba la conexión a Internet
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // Si hay conexión a Internet la variable hayConexion es verdadera
        boolean hayConexion = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();

        // Si hay conexión a Internet se carga la Url, si no hay conexión a 
        // Internet se carga el mensaje de error.
        if (hayConexion) {
            String url="http://www.uniagustiniana.edu.co/";
            view.loadUrl(url);
        } else {

            String errorHtml = "<html>" +
                          "<head></head>" +
                          "<body>" +
                          "    <h3>Error: no se pudo conectar a internet</h3>" +
                          "</body></html>";

            view.loadData(errorHtml, "text/html", null);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, sigo investigando un poco acerca de estas dos clases ConnectivityManager y NetworkInfo no me  está presentando el mensaje de advertencia en este caso puede es un Fragment y lo ensayé tambien en una Activity, lo estoy revisando.

Answer (score 2):

Quiero aportar el método que uso, al ver que en las respuestas dadas no se ha tomado en cuenta la versión de Android.

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        Network[] activeNetworks = cm.getAllNetworks();
        for (Network n : activeNetworks) {
            NetworkInfo nInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(n);
            if (nInfo.isConnected())
                return true;
        }

    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (NetworkInfo anInfo : info)
                if (anInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
    }

    return false;

}
```

**Ejemplo de uso:**

```
if (isConnected(getApplicationContext())){
    //Conectado... proceder

}else{

    //No conectado

}
```