# Verificar internet App Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Necesito que mi aplicación me verifique si hay internet y si no hay me muestre un set.text diciendo que no hay.

Creo que tiene algo que ver con esta clase:

```
public class HTTPDataHandler {
static String stream = null;

public HTTPDataHandler() {


}

public String GetHTTPData(String urlString) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(line);
            stream = sb.toString();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return stream;

}
```

}

CLASE PRINCIPAL

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RssObject rssObject;

    // Posem el link que volem.

    private final String RSS_link="http://estaticos.marca.com/rss/portada.xml";
    private final String RSS_to_Json_API = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//Crreguem activity main, desorés la barra toolbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("EAC2-2017S1");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        loadRss();  // Carreguem la clase loadRSS
    }

    //Utilitzem AsyncTask per carregar dades i convertirles
    private void loadRss() {

        AsyncTask<String,String,String> loadRSSAsync = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
           // SpotsDialog mDialog = new SpotsDialog(MainActivity.this);
// No he trobat forma que SpotsDialog em funciones.. :( Així que he optat per mDialog.
           ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

            // He possat el mDialog encara que sé que està decapated.
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                mDialog.setMessage("Un moment siusplau..."); // He fet un missatje cuan carregui la app.
                mDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String result;
                HTTPDataHandler http = new HTTPDataHandler();
                result = http.GetHTTPData(params[0]);
                return result;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                rssObject = new Gson().fromJson(s,RssObject.class);
                FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter(rssObject,getBaseContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };

        StringBuilder url_get_data = new StringBuilder(RSS_to_Json_API);
        url_get_data.append(RSS_link);
        loadRSSAsync.execute(url_get_data.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        if (item.getItemId() ==R.id.menu_refresh)
            loadRss(); // ACTUALITZEM RSS
        return true;
    }

}
```

Pero la verdad es que no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo.. estoy super perdida.. si podéis ayudarme :(

gracias

Comment: mira por ejemplo, usa el método isOnline() para determinar si tienes o no conectividad : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111068/c%C3%B3mo-detectar-conexi%C3%B3n-a-internet-y-poner-un-mensaje-de-aviso-si-no-hay-conexi%C3%B3n/111121#111121 obviamente en lugar de cargar una url , es agregar un texto a un TextView mediante setText(). si quieres trata y realiza una nueva pregunta con esta información! :)

Comment: Obviamente antes de llamar GetHTTPData() se revisa si existe conectividad.

Comment: uf.. xD Creo que primero voy a empezar por buscar que es GetHTTPData y paso a paso.

Comment: Lo que realiza GetHTTPData() es descargar el contenido de un recurso en internet mediante una url,  por ejemplo un .xml o .json

Comment: el problema es adaptarlo a mi programa, eso me vuelve loca, Gracias Jorge! Sigo mirando! :*

Comment: @Montsemkd     que es lo que quieres lograr en realidad? Por lo que veo la clase `HTTDataHandler` no es tu clase principal. Puedes mostrar la clase donde la llamas.

Comment: @David necesito que cuando no haya internet me avise, la idea sería guardar todo supongo que en un cache etc.. Pero mi idea basica es mostrar un mensaje que no hay internet pero no que me pare la aplicación. Ahora mismo si abro la aplicación sin internet no funciona. Esa no es la idea..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando el siguiente método puedes determinar si existe conexión a internet y valorar si tratas de descargar los datos o solo mostrar un mensaje indicando que no se tiene internet:

```
private static ConnectivityManager manager;

public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

La implementación se realizaría dentro de tu onCreate(),

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//Crreguem activity main, desorés la barra toolbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("EAC2-2017S1");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


        if (isOnline(getApplicationContext())) { 
             loadRss();   //Si hay conexión descarga datos!
        } else {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO hay conexión!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }


    }
```

No olvides definir los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: se me había olvidado dar permisos.. que tonta estoy hoy.. Gracias @Jorgesys